# Using subscription with Cubit, need to create Timer (streamsubscription with cubit flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc, cubit

I tried to create a timer with bloc cubit but without using it in the state but it make a memory leakage.

How i can create a timer with Cubit? i.e, probably using a subscription to this timer (streamsubscription with cubit flutter)

Comment: Have you checked the example provided in the [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial)?